# Review "Skip" button acting like "No action needed"?

Tags: discussion, review

[I only review on gaming.stackexchange.com, but I post here because I assume the process to be very similar on all sites.]

When I press "Skip" on a review page, the item counter on the review overview page goes down by one. I see the same in an incognito tab, so it's not just hidden for me.
I can see the numbers on the review queues that I don't have access to yet, so I should see the number of a queue I have access to being at non-zero, even in incognito mode, right?

If I understood it correctly, skipping does not remove an item from the queue, the next reviewer will still see it. Why does the number go down then? What do other people see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300342/review-skip-button-acting-like-no-action-needed#comment976011_300342) made by [Rand al'Thor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278659/rand-althor):

> Don't pay too much attention to those item counters; they're unreliable at the best of times.

In addition, [Helmar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/338924/helmar) recommends the following general purpose resource on this topic:

> http://shouldiblamecaching.com/